# Is there a way to rename a python package upon installation?

Tags: python, windows, pip

### The Problem

I am working on a project that uses a package in beta with multiple versions (package name: `psychxr`). After some confusing error messages about missing modules, I have discovered that depending on where I source my installation from I get **different** package contents.

If I use `pip` to install `psychxr`, I get an `ovr` sub-package. However, if I install from source (via official github repository), I get a `libovr` sub-package. Is there a way I can rename the source package such that I can get both modules? Alternatively, is there a better way to go about this? Although the packages complete roughly the same task, their implementations are noticeably different, and I'd like access to both.

### CMD output of `>>>python -c help('psychxr')`

#### Version 1 (OVR)

```
NAME
    psychxr

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    ovr (package)

VERSION
    0.1.4
```

#### Version 2 (LIBOVR)

```
NAME
    psychxr

PACKAGE CONTENTS
    libovr (package)

VERSION
    0.2.0
```

Post Script: I do apologize for any misuse of terminology, or illegibility. I'm fairly new to both python and cmd in windows.

Comment: You typically want to use a virtual environment for this, such as https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/ or https://programwithus.com/learn-to-code/Pip-and-virtualenv-on-Windows/

Comment: There’s no way to solve this in general: code you don’t control can do `from psychxr import ovr` **and** (in other code) `from psychxr import libovr` and you can’t make both work without detailed understanding and/or editing.